# ~50tb of storage in Azure presented as a single Windows File Share

Tags: storage, azure, cloud, server-message-block, cloud-storage

I have googled, the closest thing I have found so far is another SF question here: [Azure Storage limitations](https://serverfault.com/questions/512725/azure-storage-limitations)

The Goal:

Move approx 50TB of storage to the cloud, present that storage as a standard Windows File Share and have it relatively easily extended as it continues to grow.

The Problem:

It appears that a single VHD can only be 1TB in size, which is no good obviously.

I don't suppose anyone here hasa solution that they could offer?

Thank you for reading,

Xavier.

Comment: 1TB is 20 times your storage requirement of 50 GB, what's the problem?

Comment: Very sorry, I should have wrote 50TB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to investigate Microsoft DFS namespaces and start segregating data within Azure - I've done a similar project. Where by you add a small separate VHD then mount further 1TB VHD's as mount points under the first drive e.g.

100GB disk Mount as D:

Then the Nth 1TB VHD would mount under D:\Disk1 ... D:\Disk50 then with DFS namespaces you can share out the data e.g. \DOMAIN\SHARES\Finance would map to \NEWFILESERVER\DISK43$\Finance etc.

Not the most ideal but will work within the current technical limits of Azure.

I hope I've explained it enough to get you started - feel free to get in touch if you need any more help.

Good luck uploading 50TB it might be worth considering if storing this data in Azure is more cost effective than storing it in offices but increasing the WAN/Internet Links. That said you wouldn't have to worry about new hardware etc then. The above solution would scale quite well I'd imagine.

Comment: 50TB in a single namespace is best done with DFS, currently.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure File Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) may be useful to you. Also as HBrujn notes above, 1TB is much more than 50GB you are looking for.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have wrote 50TB

Answer (score 0):

Azure File Storage service allows you to create file-shares up to 5TB in size, with each file being up to 1TB. This is effectively an SMB volume, with an underlying REST API. You can access this share from both Azure resources and on-premises resources.

Since you're dealing with 50TB, you'd need to create multiple File Service volumes. Azure Storage does support up to 500TB per storage account, but not as a single file share. You *can* upload files into discrete blobs, allowing for you to have access to the full 500TB, but this won't provide an SMB interface; instead, you'd have to rely on either the language-specific sdk of your choice (.net, java, python, node, ruby, php), or direct REST calls to work with these discrete objects.

As for moving content to the cloud, you can either do that with your own app (once connected to the file share) or use a tool such as AzCopy, which now supports File Service as a source/destination. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) that mentions AzCopy and how you'd use it to transfer to file Service.